# Ошибки в libGDX после обновления

Tags: java, libgdx

Обновил `libGDX`, появились 2 ошибки в классе наследуемом от `AndroidApplication`. `Class must implement get ApplicationLogger` и `setApplicationLogger`

Comment: Вас морально поддержать?

Comment: Решил проблему!